# wix installer issue for uninstalling other application

Tags: c#, wix

We have an old application in windows and new application in WPF. Requirement is to uninstall the windows product and install the WPF one.

I am using custom action to call the batch file which calls the uninstall command.
wmic product where `name="ClientDiagnostics"` call uninstall /nointeractive
exit /B

```
<CustomAction Id="UninstallOldExe"
ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]Resources\Uninstaller.bat"
Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
Execute='deferred'
Impersonate='no'
Return="asyncNoWait"/>

<Custom Action="UninstallOldExe" After="InstallFiles"><! [CDATA[$FilesComponent>2]]></Custom>
```

​

Everything is working fine but the Desktop shortcut and application menu is not getting removed.

If I just run the command every works as expected. Only through wix setup I have an issue.

Can you please help.

Comment: Your .exe file installed in new installer has new name, or same as previous .exe, which is targeted by non deleted shortcut?

Comment: It has new name, new folders and new shortcut

Comment: If the previous product was installed with an MSI file (because it's WiX or some other tool) then you can use Upgrade elements or MajorUpgrade to uninstall it. You only need to know it's UpgradeCode and the range of possible ProductVersions.

Comment: This got fixed.I had messed up with GUIDs.

Thanks,
Asma